# How do I amend wp_query before it is run/executed?

Tags: wp-query, search

Basically what I am trying to do is to have a number of input fields on my WordPress search form as follows:

```
All of these words
The exact phrase
Any of these words
None of these words
```

and then to put those together into one array to pass through to the results page. (excuse the terminology - hope that makes sense!)

What I am thinking is that, for example, if someone wanted to search posts with the word "lecture" and "2016" but not "2015" or "2014".

For example, if I input the below into the standard WordPress search field:

```
"lecture +2016 - 2014"
```

I get this in the querystring:

```
?search_query=lecture+%2B2016+-2012
```

What I am needing is to create that manually from the fields above. I would imagine that I would need to do something like put a plus sign in front of each word in the "All of these words" field and a minus sign in front of the words in the "None of these words" field?

But how do I access and change that query?

Any advice/direction would be greatly appreciated!

Thanks in advance!

This is a request from the site users so that is why I am trying to make the form a bit more intuitive rather than having users needing to use operators such as the negative sign in "-2014"

As far as I can tell what would help is if I could somehow amend/alter the "s" parameter in the search before it is actually "processed"

So if I had the following:

```
All of these words: "lecture 2016"
None of these words: "2014"
```

I could somehow extract the "s" value and then regenerate that parameter into something like:

```
$args = array (
's' => '\"lecture 2016\" -2014',
);
```

that should work - is this on the right track?

**Edit:** got the s parameter to change using:

```
function search_filter($query) {
  if ( !is_admin() && $query->is_main_query() ) {
    if ($query->is_search) {
        $query->set( 's', 'stackoverflow' );
    }
  } 
}

add_action('pre_get_posts','search_filter');
```

Comment: https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/pre_get_posts

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `pre_get_posts` to modify the query object before the query has run.  - https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/pre_get_posts

```
function exclude_category( $query ) {
    if ( $query->is_home() && $query->is_main_query() ) {
        $query->set( 'cat', '-1,-1347' );
    }
    else if ($query->is_search) {
        $query->set( 's', 'stackoverflow' );
    }      
}
add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'exclude_category' );
```

Comment: Thanks, I see that for modifying the query object but cannot seem to get it to work to change the "s" parameter.

Comment: Thanks, I now have manged to change the s parameter - not exactly  where/how I wanted on my side (!) but you have answered the question. See edit of my question.